# Plotting 3d lists with large data sets more efficiently

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have been trying to plot a set of 3D points using `ListPlot3D`. The list is very large, in fact *Mathematica* is even taking an excessive amount of time to calculate the length of the list.

Is there anything I can do to increase the efficiency of the `ListPlot3D` function for large data sets in *Mathematica*?

My end goal is to generate a 3D "mesh" plot and also maybe an animated 2D plot.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `Sort`ing the data before you plot it.  Additionally:  Do you really need all those data points?  It may be more than the screen itself can distinguish.  Excessive time to even calculate the *length* of the dataset?  Something is wrong here.  That should be nearly instantaneous, even for extremely large datasets.

Comment: For a list of $10^8$ 3D points, `Length` takes 55 seconds on my Mac Desktop machine.